# How to round the Timestamp to the nearest seconds?

Tags: python, pandas

Pls help me to round this Timestamp to seconds
I have the Dataframe Index is the series of the timestamp as below. How to round Index to the nearest second?

```
Timestamp('2019-06-16 07:53:32.961000')
```

Expected result

```
Timestamp('2019-06-16 07:53:33')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html):

```
t = pd.Timestamp('2019-06-16 07:53:32.961000')

print (t.round('S'))
2019-06-16 07:53:33
```

For `DatetimeIndex` is used [`DatetimeIndex.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html):

```
df.index = df.index.round('S')
```

For column is necessary `.dt` with [`Series.dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.round('S')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Timestamp.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html):

```
pd.Timestamp('2019-06-16 07:53:32.961000').round('s')
# Timestamp('2019-06-16 07:53:33')
```